# R using references instead of copying data (and deleting the source if not used early)

Tags: r, reference, scope, member

I am currently taking a class in R programming and was playing around with the following example function for caching the result of a potentially time consuming operation. More context on its purpose can be found on [github](https://github.com/rdpeng/ProgrammingAssignment2/blob/master/README.md):

```
makeVector <- function(x = numeric()) {
    m <- NULL

    set <- function(y) {
            x <<- y
            m <<- NULL
    }

    get <- function() {
        return(x)
    }

    getmean <- function() {
        if(!is.null(m)) {
            m <<- mean(x)
        }
        return(m)
    }

    list(set = set, get = get,
         getmean = getmean)
}
```

I stumbled upon the following strange behaviour:

When I use a temporary vector to initialize the cached vector and delete it before the cached vector object first accesses it, the cached vector forgets its contents. It throws an error when I try to access it using `get()` (I print only the length for less output):

```
> v<-1:1e6
> cv<-makeVector(v)
> rm(v)
> length(cv$get())
Error in cv$get() : object 'v' not found
```

Watching the memory usage using `library("pryr")`tells me that memory is allocated for the creation of the vector `v`, but not for `cv` (at least not enough to store `v` in it). This amount is freed when `rm(v)` is called. So there is really no accessible information on the vector's content anymore.

Now I do the same thing but I access the cached vector's contents before removing `v`. This makes it accessible even after `v` is removed.

```
> v<-1:1e6
> cv<-makeVector(v)
> length(cv$get())
[1] 1000000
> rm(v)
> length(cv$get())
[1] 1000000
```

Memory profiling suggests, that R does not copy the vector when accessing it (no significant increase in memory usage when calling `length(cv$get())`). But the memory is not freed when removing `v`. So R now has the awareness that the contents of the vector are still in use and the memory is not deallocated. Accessing it still works after `v` is removed. Removing the cached vector (`rm(cv)`) will free the memory.

Here is an example case where recycling temporary variables (which I might want to do in a loop) leads to wrong data being stored without a warning:

```
> v<-1:10
> cv1<-makeVector(v)
> v<-51:60
> cv2<-makeVector(v)
> cv1$get()
 [1] 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
> cv2$get()
 [1] 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
```

Note that I get the expected result when accessing the member variable before reinitializing `v`:

```
> v<-1:10
> cv1<-makeVector(v)
> cv1$get()
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> v<-51:60
> cv2<-makeVector(v)
> cv1$get() 
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> cv2$get()
 [1] 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
```

Is this behaviour intended or is this a bug in R? Or is this simply undefined behaviour (because it is not mentioned in the standard) and this kind of caching is more like a dirty hack that I should never use?

For reference: I am using R version 3.1.1 on a 64bit Linux system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the wacky world of lazy evaluation and promises...

When you do:

```
cv<-makeVector(v)
```

your code never evaluates `v`, it just defines some functions in the object that are going to use `v` (now called `x` as the argument name) later.

So then you `rm(v)`, and call `cv$get()`. Only at this point does `x` get looked at, and oh dear, `v` has gone.

The first time this hits you, it looks like a Heisenbug. If you put `print(x)` after the `function(x){` line, then `x` prints out okay, and the function works. Get rid of the `print(x)` and the function fails again. Observing the system seems to change the state of the system, just like Quantum Theory.

The explanation is that printing `x` evaluates `x`, and so now `x` is no longer an unevaluated promise related to `v`. You can safely remove `v`.

The conventional way to work round this is to do something that evaluates `x` in the outer function context. In the absence of any other way, use `force(x)`, which is a null-op function that evaluates its args.

In your third code fragment, calling `cv$get()` and then removing `v` works because `cv$get()` evaluates `x`, finds `v`, and all is well. `x` is now evaluated.

That explains your first problem, I'm stopping there because I suspect everything else is related...

tl;dr: just stick `force(x)` after your function definition

further reading: I suspect Hadley Wickham's Advanced R book explains this better.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I expected to be the reason. I was just unsure if it happens by design or is unintended. `force(x)` is exactly what I was looking for.